# Linux kernel memory leaks fixed so far

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, kernel, static-analysis

Is there any sane way to access all the memory leak related bugs fixed so far in linux kernel(for all versions).

My aim is to figure out from the description or fix, the cause of memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linux kernel code is version controlled in git (see https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/).

You could try to search the git commit messages for "memory leak".

For this you have to clone the repository to your local machine and then search the log:

```
git log --grep="memory leak"
```

or other similar patterns.

Comment: currently i was wondering if this can be searched on bugzilla.

Comment: I don't think that all memory leaks were reported there. I'm pretty sure that you have better changes to find more of them in the git history.

Comment: Thanks MrTux I will check on that